# How can i insert an Intelligent Mail Barcode into Pages 09 document

Tags: pages

I've Googled around for a solution to this issue but nothing is readily apparent. I have a company newsletter with existing merge fields for an address block (company, street address, etc..). The merge data is being pulled from a numbers spread sheet. The postal service will charge me extra postage per each newsletter for not including an [Intelligent Mail Barcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Mail_barcode). I am trying to figure out a method for doing so in Pages 09 version 4.3. Ideally this would just be part of the mail merge process but I am open to alternate methods to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could achieve this is a multi-part batch process, it very much depends how you need to generate your barcode though.

Do you need to from Address to barcode?
Are the addresses clean and normalised?
Do you already have, or can generate the barcode identifier?
The better your data is the easier it'll be to put this together.

If you don't have the barcode identifiers already is it possible to get a third party in your country that does address validation and partners with the postal services data to clean and add these so you've got valid addresses + barcode identifiers returned.

Assuming you can do this process, either via a third party or software, to get 
barcode identifiers into your source spreadsheet.

I'd do a multi-part mail merge, i.e:

1. Run the spreadsheet against a compliant barcode generation tool e.g. [ID Automation's Image Generator](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-generator/) output your barcodes in batch, with a unique name to a named folder.
2. In your Pages mail merge include the relevant barcode image.

Other options are using a barcode font, you've got to be careful with the source data you pass in to make sure it's a real valid barcode e.g. [IDAutomation's font](http://www.idautomation.com/barcode-fonts/usps-intelligent-mail/)

I've only recommended paid software, likely you can do the generation cheap-free in the open source world but make sure you get your barcode checked for compliance before committing to the full print run!

Comment: Helpful but a lot of hoops to jump through. I can just run my client base through a dymo labler software which will do the barcode and print the client address. I'm trying to eliminate the label all together and streamline the overall process.